# increment of a for loop with a decimal value

Tags: c++, for-loop, floating-point

first let me say that I've already checked related topics
the problem is that I want to make a for loop with a decimal step size 
I've prepared the bellow code to solve the problem, but it doesn't generate accurate number with the mentioned step size

```
 float b;


   for ( double a=-0.2; a<=0.2 ; a+=0.01)// a = landa with an increment of 0.1

    {

        b = a * 100.0;
    a = ((int)b) / 100.0;

}
```

what I want is to have a accurate number in each iteration, but as the variable defined as a double thats just close to the value that it must be.(-0.20000000001,-0.19000000002,....)
please let me know how can I solve this problem & whats wrong with the code?

Comment: 0.01 can not be expressed as sum of powers of two => it´s impossible to get an accurate 0.01 in a double.

Comment: Don't use floating-point for this type of flow-control. If you know how many iterations you need, loop over an integer.

Comment: If you want an *exact* number, why not use an integer?

Comment: Figure out the number of iterations you need to run and do the calculations within the loop. Floating point values are not safe for flow control.

Comment: @deviantfan So how should I deal with the problem?

Comment: If for whatever reason you must have exact decimals, you will likely need to look into a library like GMP.

Comment: @IMI: Look at the other comments...

Comment: @Beta they are coefficients for other values so I need double variable

Comment: Are these percents or something else with only two decimal digits? Then think everything multiplied by 100 and use ints.

Comment: You say that you looked at the related topics, but then you don't say why those answers don't apply. Given that your question doesn't show much effort (misspelled words, little capitalization and punctuation), other users are going to assume that you haven't actually reviewed what others have said on this topic.

Comment: @Beta no they are not percentage

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for (double a = -0.2; a <= 0.2; a += 0.01)
{
    ...
}
```

use an integer loop index and calculate the corresponding floating point value within the loop, e.g.

```
for (int i = -20; i <= 20 ; ++i) // a = -0.2 to 0.2 step 0.01
{
    const double a = i / 100.0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `i / 100.0` is guaranteed to be the nearest floating-point to the desired rational, whereas `i * 0.01` multiplies a number different from 1/100, and then adds a new rounding error that can go either way.

Comment: Good point - I had my code optimization hat on when I wrote the above - I've updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

To do computations with exact decimals you could use a decimal floating point class like [bdldfp::Decimal64](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bdl/bdldfp/bdldfp_decimal.h): decimal floating points don't use base 2 which computers are good at computing with but rather a base 10. As a result their processing is slower (the current implementation really isn't great using IBM's decNumber but it is being corrected to use Intel's implementation). In return decimal computations are accurate:

```
using namespace BloombergLP;
bdldfp::Decimal64 a(BDLDFP_DECIMAL64_DD(-0.2));
bdldfp::Decimal64 add(BDLDFP_DECIMAL64_DD(0.01));
bdldfp::Decimal64 end(BDLDFP_DECIMAL64_DD(0.2));
for (; a <= end; a += add) {
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

The implementation could be made to look nicer with C++11 features (e.g., using `_DD` as a literal suffix) but it is meant to run with C++03 compilers, too. I'm working on getting decimal floating point classes added to the C++ standard ([here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html) is the most recent version of the proposal).

When using binary floating points, e.g., `double` you won't be able to represent the values exactly. You probably get the closest values doing the iteration based on integers and dividing appropropriately in each iteration:

```
for (int a(-20); a <= 20; ++a) {
    std::cout << (a / 100.0) << '\n';
}
```

When using `double` directly and adding `0.01` in each iteration there will some rounding error which increases the inaccuracy of the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Use something along these lines:

```
double min = -0.2;
double max = +0.2;
int N = 40;
for(int i=0; i<=N; i++) {
    double a = min + static_cast<double>(i)*((max - min)/static_cast<double>(N));
    double b = a * 100.0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement is also a potential problem:

```
    a = ((int)b) / 100.;
```

Since (int)b is going to truncate b towards zero. For example, if b == 101.9999999999, then (int) b will produce 101 (not 102). To stay with the original concept try something like this:

```
double a;
int b;
    for(a = -.2; a <= .2; a += .01){
        b = (int)(a*100. + ((a < -0.005)? -.5 : .5));
        a = (double)b / 100.;
    }
```

Note, (a < -.005) is a check for negative a with a margin of error of 1/2 the step rate.

Still as others have posted, using an integer for the loop and setting 'a' based on the integer would be a better solution.